# C# chat wpf application

Tags: c#, chat

As I understand, it's possible to write a chat application (server + client) without any web server. As a server we can use just a class listening to TCP port.
As a client we can also use a class.

So it's possible to write this application within one WPF application, is it so or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes. You can do this easily using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services. But at least one of your chat endpoints would have to specify the IP address of the other.

Note that this has got nothing to do with WPF. WPF is just the way of drawing the application / controls. This would work with Windows Forms applications as well.

Comment: and if both client and server are on one machine and their IP addresses are the same, what's the solution?

Comment: @Sergey - well then you just enter "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" as ip address. This works.

Comment: @Sergey - Yes it also works with many clients. Do you want to have each client communicate with each other client? Like an n-to-n relationship? This is possible but it will create a lot of traffic. I would recommend to use 1 server to distribute the messages to each client which is connected to the server. In this way, each client only needs to know the ip address of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do just as you've described... one class for the server and one for the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm understanding you correctly, but if not let me know.

It is possible to write a chat *client* in a single WPF application, however if you're building a chat application in the client-server model then you'll also need a chat *server*, which in all likelihood will not be a WPF app.